# Hibernate does not log stacktrace

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

I have hibernate logs configured via log4j:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
```

In case of error I only get exception message not full stacktrace:

```
[APPNAME] 2014-09-08 15:44:40,487 ERROR [http-bio-808-exec-3] SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(146) | ERROR: column user0_.nationality does not exist
  Position: 1365
```

because SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions() has:

```
public void logExceptions(SQLException sqlException, String message) {
        if ( LOG.isEnabled( Level.ERROR ) ) {
            if ( LOG.isDebugEnabled() ) {
                message = StringHelper.isNotEmpty( message ) ? message : DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_MSG;
                LOG.debug( message, sqlException );
            }
            final boolean warnEnabled = LOG.isEnabled( Level.WARN );
            while ( sqlException != null ) {
                if ( warnEnabled ) {
                    LOG.warn( "SQL Error: " + sqlException.getErrorCode() + ", SQLState: " + sqlException.getSQLState() );
                }
                LOG.error( sqlException.getMessage() );
                sqlException = sqlException.getNextException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now after I activate DEBUG for whole hibernate, it does print stackTrace then but have a lot of garbage logged. What can I do to log stackTraces  only?

Marking logger for package have class `SqlExceptionHelper` to DEBUG can solve the problem but not sure I'll get all error logs hibernate ever produce.

Any help?

Comment: what is `LOG` in your code?

Comment: SqlExceptionHelper is an hibernate class that uses BasicLogger.

Answer (score 0):

To see the stack trace, you need to use

```
LOG.error(sqlException.getMessage(), sqlException);
```

Can you extend SqlExceptionHelper and override the logExceptions method so that it uses this line instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
    #log4j.rootLogger=@replaced.log4j.rootLogger@
log4j.appender.logfile.File=@replaced.log4j.appender.logfile@

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=512KB
# Keep three backup files
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#Pattern to output : date priority [category] - <message>line_separator
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.category.net.sf.acegisecurity=INFO
log4j.category.com.dc=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.apache.myfaces=INFO
log4j.category.javax.faces=INFO

# logs the SQL statements
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

# Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
```

Above log4j settings should help and then All you need to use is

LOGGER.error(e,e) //where  e is exception object

Hope this helps